# augment the number of lines on indent

Tags: vim

in my `.vimrc` file, I have `set ts=2` and that works - that is, it pushes the text two spaces to the right - when i'm using tab to indent in insert mode.

Indenting with `>>`, however, pushes the text 7 spaces to the right.  How can I control how many spaces `>>` inserts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's controlled by the `'shiftwidth'` option; it should be aligned with `'tabstop'` to give consistent results:

```
:set ts=2 sw=2
```